# If statement inside loop not reading total right cout displaying wrong

Tags: c++

Hello all I want to do is for last cout statement display whatever apartment has the highest rent and the apartment name. Right now it displays the total rent of all complexes enter and whatever the last complex name entered. I am stuck on this and could really use some help on this. I am new to c++ so please talk to me in layman terms it is hard for me to understand somethings.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("rentfile.txt");
    int numComplex, numMonths;
    double rent, totalAllRent = 0; //// Accumulator for total scores
    string nameComplex;
    string highNameComplex;
    double averageRent;
    double highestRentTotal = 0;

    //set up numeric output programing
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

    cout << "How many complexes will you enter?";
    cin >> numComplex;   //number of complexes enter
    cout << "How many months of rent will you enter complex?";
    cin >> numMonths; //number of months of rent enter

    for (int complex = 1; complex <= numComplex; complex++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Complex Name ";
        cin >> nameComplex;
        outputFile << nameComplex << " ";

        for (int months = 1; months <= numMonths; months++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Rent " << months << " for ";
            cout << " Complex " << complex << ": ";
            cin >> rent;
            outputFile << rent << endl; //write data to output file 
            totalAllRent = totalAllRent + rent;

            if (totalAllRent > highestRentTotal)
            {
                highNameComplex = nameComplex;
                highestRentTotal = totalAllRent;
            }

            averageRent = totalAllRent / numComplex;

        }
    }
    outputFile.close(); //close the file

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("rentfile.txt");
    cout << "Complex Monthly rent Collected per Complex " << endl;

    while (inputFile >> nameComplex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numMonths; i++)
        {
            inputFile >> rent;
            cout << nameComplex << " " << rent << endl;
            if (rent == 0)
                cout << "Warning one of the complexes submitted zero rent for one of the months " << endl;
            }
    }

            cout << "Total rent collected for the company = " << totalAllRent << endl;
            cout << " Average Monthly rent collected for the company = " << averageRent << endl;
            cout << highNameComplex << "collect the most rent = " << highestRentTotal << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...if it's me, I'll design the program as follows:
1. Define a `vector<vector<double>> vvRents` for storing the rents of all apartments by month.
2. Each element in `vvRents` stores the rents of all months of each apartment.
3. Once all data is collected, calculate summed rents of the year by apartment, and store the total rents in a new vector `vTotalRents`.
4. Use a `max_element` algorithm to pick the most expensive apartment.
You must include `<vector>` to use `vector` class, and include `<algorithm>` to use `max_element`.